# Du kommst auch nicht zu kurz

Tags: meaning

I could not find the meaning of this sentence. Can anyone help me to understand it? I asked one of my German friends, but he was not able to clearly explain. He just said it is irony.

Can someone here clarify?

The English dictionary translation ("also you don't come short") is similarly meaningless to me, as its original.

Comment: The infinitive would be "zu kurz kommen": https://www.dict.cc/?s=zu+kurz+kommen

Comment: This is said often (for example to kids): "Du kommst schon nicht zu kurz."

Answer (score 5):

The English translation would be `to miss out`. It basically means that you will get your fair share of something, e.g. an apple or when inheriting money.

Often told to kids as they often can't oversee when siblings are getting something and they aren't, e.g. on one's birthday or when sharing sweets.

Comment: Thanks. got it.

Answer (score 4):

I would translate the phrase as:

> You'll also get your fair share.

It may be meant in the way Joe described - without any irony.

However, the sentence can also express some kind of threat in an ironic way.
 Example: When a student is visibly amused about the answers of another student, the teacher might use this sentence to remind him that he is among the next to be questioned.

Comment: Thanks. got it.

Comment: To distinguish between normal and ironic meaning you will need tone and context (or at least one of them).

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have it roughly correct, which can be lexicalized as *you are short on [money, time, supplies ...]*, the comparisons run deep.

Compare "to curtail someone"; cp "jemanden seiner Rechte beschneiden", "die Schere wird immer breiter", "ungeschoren davon kommen"; "you still come up three dollars short, you still owe me", "zu schulden kommen lassen". "Es wird eng", "money is tight" (*money is tied up*), "kurz angebunden".